# Jar loading files

Tags: java, web-applications, jar, plist

I have a jar file which have 15 classes. I have to call some methods of this jar from web application. Some of the methods read .plist file.

In the jar code I have coded in such a way that all the plist files are readed once and uses multiple times(I have used some static map which hold all the properties of .plist files), but this is not happening.

Every time there is a call it is reading all .plist files again. And because of this there is "Too Many Open File Exception."

Is there any way to stop the file reading again and again. Please help me.

Answer (score 0):

Can you post your code or stack trace. it looks like a logical problem . If you want to read file  once just have a static flag and after reading it set it true and before reading it just check....If this is not the desired answer just let me know .